# magento 2 override to custom module

Tags: magento2, overrides

Can anyone help me how to override the following files to custom module

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Item.php

vendor/magento/module-sales/Api/Data/OrderItemInterface.php
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `preference` in Magento 2 to override any class but you can use `plugins` to inject your method to `after/around/before` any method for any class method. Please donot confuse plugins as extension, in Magento 2 plugin (a class ) is a way to inject your method to another method.

See preference examples in this Magento 2 documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html

You just need to define **preference** `for` and `type` where for represent source class and type represent target class.

**Updated**: 
You have to define metadata class object so that your orderRepository can get it. So please use this as below:
Define just after preference in your XML.

```
<type name="Ewall\Sales\Model\OrderRepository">
<arguments>
    <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="object">orderMetadata</argument>
</arguments></type>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Kumar,  can you please check the question again i have updated my di.xml file thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer see above.

Comment: If you want to do some changes via virtual type in your classes for order item and order class then you can keep it otherwise just remove it because it's already been defined in Magento it's self.

Comment: ok but iam facing errors, actually my intension is to get item ordered product image, I did it in vendor files and result is https://prnt.sc/i4c51b but unable to override to custom module

Comment: What error you are getting

Answer (score 2):

Create your own module.
In the `di.xml` file of your module add this

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Sales\Order\Item" />

<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Sales\Order\Item" />
```

Then create the class `[Vendor]\[Module]\Sales\Order\Item` that extends `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item` and implements `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface`.
But I doubt you need both of them in `di.xml`. I have a feeling that the second one only will solve your problem

Comment: thanks for the reply marius , can you please check the question again i have updated my di.xml file thanks